# portable IIS or other server for asp.net app

Tags: asp.net, iis, portable-applications

I'm looking for a portable version of server for simple app (no db) writen in asp.net 4. I need to present it from pendrive in few places and I don't know what systems there are. Is something like that available somewhere?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is now a portable version of IIS available called IIS Express. Read more here : http://www.basarat.com/2011/05/protable-iis-iis-express-75.html

Comment: Am getting 404 error. The url might have changed.

Comment: Link : http://basaratali.blogspot.com.au/2011/05/protable-iis-iis-express-75.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one from Codeproject. It seems to be exactly what you need: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/TinyWebServer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've used Ulti-dev's server. 
http://ultidev.com/products/Cassini/index.htm

it is based on "Cassini" but comes with an installer. 
I've run ASPX pages and  ASPNET MVC2 services on this thing.

I haven't stressed it, but I've 
never had a problem.